# Why redirection with tee doesn't work as expected?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, tee

What I want to obtain is logging all the output of a script to a file, all in the script itself, saving all I see on the screen in the log file. 
If I don't redirect to file the script works as intended, continuing to loop forever till I hit CTRL+C; when this happens it prints a couple of messages on screen and quits.
If I try to redirect to a file, using tee, not only it doesn't print the messages but also the log is incomplete, there's only the loop lines, nothing afte that.
Here's the script (cut down version):

```
#!/bin/sh
EXIT=0
COUNT=0
{
while [ $EXIT -eq 0 ]
do
  COUNT=$((COUNT+1)) && echo "Eternal loop $COUNT" && sleep 1
  trap 'EXIT=1; echo "Loop interrupted by user, exiting."' 15 2 8 20
done
echo "Out of loop, eternity ends"
} | tee log.log 2>&1
```

I read around and couldn't understand if the issue I have is caused by piping to tee, by stderr and stdout, or by how I useda trap.
I'm a noob at shell scripting and this is frustrating, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit 1:
After reading chepner's answer I modified the script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
EXIT=0
COUNT=0
rm log.log
while [ $EXIT -eq 0 ]
do
COUNT=$((COUNT+1)) && echo "Eternal loop $COUNT" | tee -a log.log && sleep 1
trap 'EXIT=1; echo "Loop interrupted by user, exiting." | tee -a log.log' 15 2 8 20
done
echo "Out of loop, eternity ends" | tee -a log.log
```

and it works, it logs the output to a logfile, and I still see the output on screen, exactly how I wanted. Will have to try it on the other script, but I suppose it'll be OK.
Now a question remains: if I have lots of commands instead of just 3, would this solution be "clean" enough? I mean, what happens to all those tee I call forth?  Is there a better way to do this, like more polished?

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you're asking, but when you want to log everything you see during a process, the script command is easier than dealing with redirection.

if you want to use tee anyway, move the redirection in front of the pipe

```
somecommand 2>&1 | tee outfile
```

Comment: I'm not set on using tee, I just need the screen output to be logged. You say "the script command is easier than dealing with redirection": what do you mean by that? Can you make some examples? Thanks.

Comment: The unix command script. You type "script somefile.log", it says "script started, file is somefile.log" and then it records everything that appears on the screen until you type exit in that file.

Comment: using the script command does log all that appears on the screen, but I don't see it on the screen at the same time.

Comment: This worked for me. Regular pipe and `tee` or `tee -a` commands without `2>&1` did not work in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With the pipeline, the foreground job consists of two processes, one for each side of the pipeline. Hitting Control-C sends `SIGINT` to *all* processes, so that there is no chance for the post-loop `echo` to run, or for `tee` to output the final output of the LHS process. Without the pipe to `tee`, the `while` loop is running entirely inside the current  shell instance, so the the shell itself receives the `SIGINT` and (I believe) only interrupts whatever shell command is currently running in the loop. The trap fires, and then the loop exits naturally as a result of the condition check on `EXIT`.

Comment: Oh, this is some detailed info, thanks. So I should find another way to log the script output I presume, since using redirection and tee interferes with the trap.

Comment: Rereading your answer made me realize tee would work if I used it for every command I need the output, so I modified the script a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and then pipe to `tee` command:

```
...
} 2>&1 | tee log.log
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but the resut is the same; I think it is for the reason in chepner answer.